# Active Record Associations - Which Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm part way through the [first section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark) of the Active Record Associations Guide and got to this line:

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```

In which controller would this appear?  I assume this would be for a create action but I'm not sure if this would be in the customers controller or the orders controller.  Which is it?

Comment: You create order here, so orders_controller would be suitable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would most likely be in the orders_controller in the create action.